# Blazor server side doesn't work on Docker with MariaDB

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb, blazor-server-side

I have 2 docker containers which are connected, one is a mariaDB one. The other one is my C# .Net 6 blazor application. The database container is set up correctly and is running (it has data). The application unfortunately doesn't load in the browser. The db connection is configured right, blazor is configured right and there are no errors besides:

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

```yaml
version: "3.4"

volumes:
  datafiles:


services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: eventtimeline
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_USER: gebruiker
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
  mvc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /EventTimeline/wwwroot:/src/EventTimeline/wwwroot
      - /EventTimeline/root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/2.18.2/staticwebassets/:/root/.nuget/packages/plotly.blazor/2.18.2/staticwebassets/
      - /EventTimeline/root/.nuget/packages/mudblazor/6.11.1/staticwebassets/:/root/.nuget/packages/mudblazor/6.11.1/staticwebassets/
      - /src/obj/Release/net6.0/scopedcss/bundle/:/src/obj/Release/net6.0/scopedcss/bundle/
      - /src/EventTimeline/obj/Release/net6.0/scopedcss/bundle/:/src/EventTimeline/obj/Release/net6.0/scopedcss/bundle/
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DBHOST=db
      - DBPASSWORD=password
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
```

I cannot reach it via localhost:8080 nor 0.0.0.0:8080.

```
# Stage for restoring dependencies
FROM debian:buster-slim AS debian
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Base Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Copy project files and restore dependencies
FROM base AS restore
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["EventTimeline/EventTimeline.csproj", "EventTimeline/"]
RUN dotnet restore "EventTimeline/EventTimeline.csproj"

# Build Stage
FROM restore AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "EventTimeline/EventTimeline.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish Stage
FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet publish "EventTimeline/EventTimeline.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Final Stage
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EventTimeline.dll"]


Output:
2024-01-17 13:22:05 Blazor added
2024-01-17 13:22:05 Added static files
2024-01-17 13:22:05 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2024-01-17 13:22:05 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       No XML encryptor configured. Key {24098cd6-0d0d-4554-a0a6-c169c9e4aeda} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2024-01-17 13:22:05 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
2024-01-17 13:22:05 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-01-17 13:22:05 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       Hosting environment: Development
2024-01-17 13:22:05 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-17 13:22:05       Content root path: /app/
```

Comment: It seems like you set up port 8080 within `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080`, but exposed 80. Also, try to log into the container and `curl http://localhost:{your_port}` to see whether it's a problem between the host and container or just in container.

Comment: Also don't you need a `dbdata:/var/lib/mysql` in the MariaDB volumes for data persistence? But agree with @sly `"8080:8080"` appears to be the problem/solution for initial app connectivity. Nice clear layering on image - though `debian` appears unused.